# How do I get the object passed to a generic class

Tags: java, generics, casting, jax-rs, runtime

I have this wrapper class

```
public class ResultList<T> {

    private Class<T> entityClass;

    public ResultList(Class<T> entityClass){this.entityClass=entityClass;}

    public Class<T> getEntity(){return this.entityClass;}
}
```

In another class I create the **ResultList** object

```
ResultList result = new ResultList<User>(User.class);
```

In a runtime method (inside Provider) i have the following situation

```
@Override
public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> type) {
    if (type.isAssignableFrom(ResultList.class))
     //this is true
}
```

Can I get the **User** class passed to **ResultList** ?

If not, Can I get the **ResultList** object from `Class<?> type` and call the `getEntity()` method

Comment: You are getting passed a `Class<?>`, there is no way to get a `ResultList` instance from that. Your `if` check only checks if `type` is a super class of `ResultList`, there is no actual instance of `ResultList` involved here.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?  Having a generic class that stores a class seems a bit strange.  As I read your question, I keep thinking there's something here that you haven't understood, but I can't put my finger on what it is.

Comment: I'm using jackson and I wanted to instantiate an ObjectMapper for any class  passed to the wrapper, but I figured I could not get runtime type